# SQL IF / CASE how TO

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've been trying research online on how to combine "If" statements into my query. Suppose I wanted to create a query such that I want to create a extra column called "HIGH_VALUE", and then include a if else statement such that "If Value = "A" > "B" then  = "Value A", Else "value B" AS "HIGH_VALUE".

Answer (score 0):

In MS Access, you use `IIF()`.  It is a little unclear what logic you really want, but the idea is:

```
IIF(A > B, "Value A", "Value B") as value
```

Comment: Thanks worked - The syntax for inserting existing column name for "value A" and different "column B" was my issue - working as expected